# Android:HttpClient does not run in Android 4.0 API

Tags: android

I have written the code it works on Android 2.2 API but it does not work on Android 4.0

```
 String url = textUrl.getText().toString();
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet  request = new HttpGet(url);
     try
     {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        textResult.setText(HttpHelper.request(response));
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         textResult.setText("Failed");
    }
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: it generate Exception and I don't get the response from URL

Comment: Where is your code ? If in Activity's `onCreate()` then use `AsyncTask`..

Comment: I have written code on onCrenate() method

Comment: @user1635564 Please post error logcat and full code of mainactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Internet communication must run in a separate thread.

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to simplify this.

You can read more about threads in Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

EDIT: If you really want to access the internet on the main thread, you can allow it in the `onCreate()` method with the following code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

However, I really wouldn't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the URL from the main thread in android 2.x then it will be perfectly run.

But HonyCumb and its upper version you need to send call the URL from worker thread.

You can use **AsyncTask** for that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
The solution is very simple:
You have to use AsyncTaks. To Implement them you can simply make a new class. p.e:

```
public class AsynkTaskRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String answer = null;

        for (String request : params) {
            //your code comes here
        }
    }
}
```

For more details just search a bit and you will find it ("[i've searched for you this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)")

**EDIT:**
Don't use:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
     textResult.setText("Failed");
}
```

do it like

```
catch (Exception e) {
    //if you use logcat in eclipse    
    Log.e("Request Error", e.getMessage());
    //else
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());     
}
```