# Socket closed in network only v4.0 ksoap2

Tags: android, sockets, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

im using ksoap2 library, works fine but when i use  android 4.0 and im over 3G, when i try to set the connection always the socket is closed.
I was read is about connection keep-alive but i dont know how do set this property.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In library source HttpConectionSE.java set property connection to keep-alive compile package and use.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late four you, but I hope this would help to future people reaching here like me, getting crazy with the same problem.

**It's an Android bug**. Everything works right with WiFi, but it crashes on 3G. It happened to me on 4.1, but no problem on 4.2.2.

To solve it, you have to modify the file **org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE** (I've extended a new one and called it MyHttpTransportSE because I'm using ksoap2 assembly jar).
Just override method *public void call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope)* commenting out the line:

```
    //connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

Of course, if you're working with SSL, you'll need to extend your own *HttpsTransportSE* from your new *MyHttpTransportSE*.

More details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ksoap2-android/closed/ksoap2-

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 does not allow you to run internet communication on the main thread.
Go with `AsyncTask`

You an read more [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Alternatively, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193758/androidhttpclient-does-not-run-in-android-4-0-api/).

Comment: By wifi works fine, its only in 3G. The code is in asyntask. The error is because ksoap2 use conection closed as property.